# How to get x y position where user has touched on screen in android?

Tags: android

Hi
I want to get x and y position of screen where the user has touched. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends a little on the way you're doing your view. Usually you attach an event listener to your view in your onCreate() method. [More here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html#EventListeners)

If you have a custom view then you might use a handler instead, which means you override the onTouch() method in your view.

Either way you'll get an event object which has the x and y values.

Comment: I am using click listener and all I get is View object which does not have any knowledge of X, Y positions.

Comment: Yes, you want the touch listener. The click listener is a more abstract thing. It _can_ be triggered by a touch but it can also be triggered by other means where x any y would not make sense.